# Rails generated sql query with WHERE 0 = 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

We run a web app on ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.19 and phusion passenger 3.0.19. After upgrading the ruby to 2.1.5 & phusion passenger to 4.0.57, we encountered some strange db errors.

Rails generated some strange queries like following one and some queries without `where` clause.

`UPDATE device SET checked_in_at = '2015-04-08 06:59:45', updated_at = '2015-04-08 06:59:45' WHERE 0 = 0`

Whereas the actual query should have been:

`UPDATE device SET checked_in_at = '2015-04-08 06:59:45', updated_at = '2015-04-08 06:59:45' WHERE id = 321213`

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other methods 
  def check_in!
    self.checked_in_at = Time.zone.now
    self.save(:validate => false)
  end
end

class DeviceController < ApplicationController
  # other methods
  # PUT /devices/:device_guid_id

  def update
    device = Device.find_by_guid(params[:device_guid_id])
    device.check_in!
  end
end
```

It's occurred only once.
No trace of sql injections.

Can any point out where things might have gone wrong.

Comment: Post you rails code for the above SQL query

Comment: beware of SQL injection man

Comment: @Orion is it possible to have a sql injection here? We are suspecting ruby or phussion passenger upgrade. May be something related to concurrency?

Comment: Not an answer but why not change the `check_in!` method. `update_attribute(:checked_in_at, Time.zone.now)` will perform both your steps as it called `save(validate: false)` anyway. And no SQL injection could not have possibly impacted this query as it does not accept any arguments from an end user.

Comment: I don't see how this could come from Rails if it only happened once. I think SQL injection on another controller action, or maybe someone was testing and their query went into the log, or something else...